# Filtering User Access to Routes by Role using Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have 2 different user roles, administrator and client.

How can I create a filter so that when a user is logged in the administrator role can access
the routes that can create, update, delete, read while the client role can only access the
read routes? Without using modules.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using [route filters](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters).

```
Route::filter('auth.isAdmin', function()
{
    // Get authenticated user
    $user =  Auth::user()

    if (!$user->isAdmin()) {

        // Redirect user away, display an error message, log attempt, whatever...
    } 
});
```

Create the `isAdmin` method in your User model:

```
public function isAdmin($permission)
{
   // if user has admin role
       // return true 
   // else
       // return false
}
```

You can now protect your pages by attaching the filter to the relevant routes.

```
Route::get('foo/bar', array(
    'before' => 'auth.isAdmin'
));
```